# Trying to fix slideshow (Horizontal + Vertical)

Tags: javascript, html, background, slideshow, background-color

Script here: http://jsfiddle.net/dt5Se/ , or below:

```
var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
dimensions: [720, 478], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
imagearray: [
    ["images/indeximages/1.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/2.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/3.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/4.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/5.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/6.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/7.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/8.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/9.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/10.jpg"],
    ["images/indeximages/11.jpg"] // no comma for last image
],
displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:4000, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
descreveal: "ondemand",
togglerid: ""})
```

Is there a way I can make this work for both vertical and horizontal images? It's killing me...

See implementation here: http://www.phillipehan.com/
As you can see the 3rd image is surrounded in black on either side. How can I fix this?

Thanks!